# How to view custom type in elm?

Tags: elm

here is data model , the goal is easy, just to view the type `Gift` in the HTML and user can use a dropdown list to update field `type_` of `Gift`. But the question is how to build dropdown list from a custom type ?

```
type Fruit
    = Apple
    | Banana
    | Orange

type alias Gift = 
{ quantity : int
  type_ : Fruit
}
```

I tried to add a `update/view` operation on view

how to convert the type `Fruit` to String ? There are two possible workarounds:

1. Building a dict, which mays `Fruit` to `String`

   ```
    {Apple:"Apple",Banana,"Banana"}
   ```

   I don't think this will work since key in `Dict`  needs to be `Comparable`,but how to implement ordering in `custom type` ? there was an issue but there seems no solution yet (https://github.com/elm/compiler/issues/774)
2. Using `Enum/makeEnum` module
   this will bring more code and easily can break.

   ```
    fruitTypeEnum = Enum.makeEnum [Apple, Banana, Orange ]

    -- in view
    (List.map (\x -> Enum.toString fruitTypeEnum x) [Apple,Banana,Orange])
   ```

   this has to maintain `apple,banana,orange` list in three places ( including the declaration )

Thank you for your time reading this .Appreciate any help:)

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. Create multiple posts for multiple questions instead, referencing each other if needed. See [ask] for more on why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll only answer the first question here (see my comment). No `Dict` needed, it's a simple function:

```
fruitToString : Fruit -> String
fruitToString fruit =
  case fruit of
    Apple -> "Apple"
    Banana -> "Banana"
    Orange -> "Orange"
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no built in way in Elm to get a list of all of the variants of a custom type (Elm generally shies away from "magic" metaprogramming in favor of explicitness). [As glennsl answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70731856/2688), using a `case` expression is a very clean and straightforward way to implement a `toString` function for a custom type.

The list of all variants of that type must be keep separately from the type definition itself, but you should create one list, maybe named `allFruit` in this case, that you can use anywhere you want to list them all out. Tests can help you ensure you don't miss anything when asking a new variant.

One more advanced technique is using [code generation](https://elm-radio.com/episode/code-generation) to create a list from the source code automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the other question about using other types as keys in Dict, there is the possibility to use `assoc-list` instead: https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/pzp1997/assoc-list/latest/

```
import AssocList as Dict exposing (Dict)


type Fruit
    = Apple
    | Banana
    | Orange


fruitStrings : Dict Fruit String
fruitStrings =
    Dict.fromList
        [ ( Apple, "Apple" )
        , ( Banana, "Banana" )
        , ( Orange, "Orange" )
        ]


fruitToString : Fruit -> String
fruitToString fruit =
    Dict.get fruit fruitStrings |> Maybe.withDefault "Not a fruit"
```

As you can see, with a `Dict` you need to handle a case that could never happen. The case construction is therefore preferable here. But now you know how to create a dictionary with custom types as keys.